# Unable to parse json response swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

jsonResponse has two keys and it's values are are not actual value.

Code:

```
var responseDictionary = jsonResponse as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
var statusDictionary = responseDictionary["status"] as Array<AnyObject>
```

Results of statusDictionary

```
2 values
 {
  [0] = <error: use of undeclared identifier 'cocoarr'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
>

  [1] = <error: use of undeclared identifier 'cocoarr'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
>
```

Result of responseDictionary:

```
(lldb) po responseDictionary
 {
  [0] = {
    key = "status"
    value = (instance_type = Builtin.RawPointer = 0x00007fbb13dd0ee0 -> 0x0000000106aaf380 (void *)0x0000000106aaf3a8: __NSCFArray)
  }
  [1] = {
    key = "lastRunTime"
    value = (instance_type = Builtin.RawPointer = 0x00007fbb13dd0f70 -> 0x0000000106aae980 (void *)0x0000000106aae930: __NSCFString)
  }
}
```

Which results unable to parse the values.

If i do "po println(responseDictionary)". I can see the proper results.
What is wrong in parsing?

Thanks

Comment: You haven't shown any code where you try to do any parsing. Don't worry too much what the debugger says, it sometimes gives spurious results.

Comment: Do you know that your json is valid? Have you checked it out with one of the online validators?

Comment: Yes, it's a valid response. Checked in http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: Do you understand the JSON syntax?  Do you know how JSON gets mapped to iOS objects?  Do you understand how NSLog displays iOS objects?  (And have you attempted to code anything, or figure it out yourself?)

Comment: @Hot Licks. This how parse json object in swift. It was working fine. There is a new deployment happened. Since that time i'm getting like above error. Json object is valid and key changes in it. and FYI i did post after i tried different ways. Maybe you do without.

Comment: I'm guessing Swift garbles the dictionary listings, so they don't look like iOS object dumps, but it appears that your requests were rejected by the other end.  The values kind of look like Parse objects, but you didn't say you're using Parse.

Comment: I have mentioned that while parsing i'm getting error. So, everything you are guessing and thinking. Why did you down voted.

Answer (score 1):

The Swift Programming Language book says

> “Use the forced form of the type cast operator (as) only when you are sure that the downcast will always succeed. This form of the operator will trigger a runtime error if you try to downcast to an incorrect class type.”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/us/jEUH0.l

When you are parsing JSON and converting it to native Swift objects, you should make no assumptions about the structure of the JSON. You should use the safer form of the type cast operator, the optional form.

Using unit tests (or a Playground) is a good place to start when deserializing JSON. See the sample unit test below.

```
    func testExample() {
        var jsonString  = "{" +
        "\"lastRunTime\" : \"2004-05-06T14:13:55\"," +
        "\"status\" : [" +
        "\"finished\"," +
        "\"processed\"" +
        "]" +
    "}";

        var jsonData = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true);
        XCTAssertNotNil(jsonData);

        if let jsonDataObject : NSData = jsonData {
            var error : NSError?;
            let options : NSJSONReadingOptions = NSJSONReadingOptions();

            var deserializedJson : AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonDataObject, options: options, error: &error);

            XCTAssertNil(error);
            if nil == error {
                if let jsonDictionary = deserializedJson as? NSDictionary {
                    if let statusArray = jsonDictionary["status"] as? NSArray {
                        if let firstStatus = statusArray.firstObject as? String {
                            print(firstStatus);

                        }
                        else {
                            XCTFail("the status array should contain strings");
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        XCTFail("the json dictionary should contain a property whose name is status and whose value is an array");
                    }
                }
                else {
                    XCTFail("json should have been deserialized to a dictionary at the highest level");
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

As an aside, don't rely too heavily on the debugger when working with Swift. It does not report object values as cleanly as it does for Objective-C.

Comment: Good explanation. i have parsed the json object same as you did. The fact is, as "rdlmar" mentioned above that debugger says, it sometimes gives spurious results.  Now i can able to parse after I handled null and nil values.

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad it helped. You and rdlmar are right.